# how to pass value from php to python and the python will return the value and echo it using php again

Tags: php, python, python-2.7

How to pass a value from php to python

```
<?php $print_this = "hello world";
//pass it to python. then echo it in here. "hello world";
?>
```

how will i pass the value of a variable from php to python and the python will return it and the php will echo it.

```
import sys
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = '''http://www.kumby.com/avatar-the-last-airbender-book-3-chapter-5/'''
#open and read page
page = urllib.urlopen(url)
html = page.read()
#create BeautifulSoup parse-able "soup"
soup = BS(html)
#get the src attribute from the video tag


        video = soup.find("iframe").get("src")
        print video
```

the variable url should come from the php. where in php ,

$url = website

and in that  my python code should be

url = $url

or  i dont know how. i just heard that the php can call the python. so i was thinking is it possible to pass the variable of php to python .

now the value of variable video should be echoed in php.

Comment: what??? it is unclear what you are attempting to do

Comment: @JoranBeasley , sorry . what I'm trying to do is pass the value of a variable of php and print it via python

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid i will add my python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need Python as PHP has [multiple ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) to parse HTML/XML.

Here is an example using the [DOM extension](http://www.php.net/dom):

```
<?php

  $url = "http://www.kumby.com/avatar-the-last-airbender-book-3-chapter-5/";
  $page = new DOMDocument;
  $page->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));
  foreach ($page->getElementsByTagName('iframe') as $node) {
    echo $node->getAttribute('src');
  }

?>
```

Comment: woah! is this really possible? oh my god it takes me two days searching a way to get the url of the video O.O

Comment: You need to have the xml bindings for PHP installed and `allow_url_fopen` to be enabled in `php.ini`.

Comment: Oh my god. what is that. I'm a new programmer. I'm running my code in a server centOS 6.4 . what should i do then?

Comment: Why don't you open another question - with the exact code you are running and the error that you are getting. That way others can also chip in and help. Don't forget to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), it helps with your reputation and people are more willing to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You could pipe it:

```
php myscript.php | python myscript.py
```

Comment: i figured he was looking for something more like `echo exec("python $print_this")` +1 though cause you could just as easily have interpreted it correct

Answer (score 1):

you can use $_GET to send the variable to the python script and your python can return the value as api... or may be u can use curl() in php